# How to use d3 rotate?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm setting up a D3 demo for a math class and want a triangle to rotate about one of its vertices.  When D3 executes the rotation instruction, the triangle ends up at the correct end point but flies in and out of view during the rotation animation.

I know I'll have to adjust the images so the entire rotation is visible but I don't understand why the triangle "flies" away instead of pivoting about the vertex as I intend. I want the triangle to pivot about the midpoint of a rectangle's top horizontal line.

FWIW, the idea is to eventually transform the rectangle into a trapezoid.

What's the correct rotation syntax to achieve the pivot?

Here's the entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
    svg { width:100%; height: 400px }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

    var data = [  
      {'x': 40, 'y': 40}, 
      {'x': 40, 'y': 100},
      {'x': 200, 'y': 100},  
      {'x': 200, 'y': 40},  
      {'x': 40, 'y': 40},

    ];

    var line = d3.svg.line()
                 .x(function(d) { return  (d['x']); })
                 .y(function(d) { return  (d['y']); });

    var path = svg.append('path').attr('d', line(data))
    .style("stroke","steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width","1px")
    .style("fill","none")

    var tdata = [  
      {'x': 120, 'y': 40}, 
      {'x': 200, 'y': 70}, 
      {'x': 200, 'y': 40}, 
      {'x': 120, 'y': 40},

      ]; 

      tpath = svg.append('path').attr('d', line(tdata))
      .style("stroke", "red")
      .style("stroke-width","1px")
      .style("fill","none")
      .transition().delay(2000)     
       .duration(1000)
       .attr("transform", "rotate(-180,120,40)");

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `rotate` tries to rotate around the centre point `(0,0)` and interpolates a transform which accomplishes this.

If you want to rotate around somewhere else you can define your own interpolation between the start `rotate(0,120,40)` and end `rotate(-180,120,40)` positions:

```
tpath = svg.append('path').attr('d', line(tdata))
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .style("stroke-width","1px")
  .style("fill","none")
  .transition().delay(2000)     
  .duration(1000)
  .attrTween("transform", function(d,i,a){ return interp });

var interp = d3.interpolateString( "rotate(0,120,40)", "rotate(-180,120,40)" )
```

Comment: That has the desired effect, thanks. However, it's not clear to me why it's needed when the original rotation call is specifying where the rotation center is.  I get that svg rotates about 0,0. I don't get why d3 doesn't abstract that detail away.